# why npm install -g firebase-tools request has been deprecated

Tags: request, npm-install, git-bash, deprecated

I'm trying to deploy react application to firebase using Github actions.
On the git bash terminal I typed:

`$ npm install -g firebase-tools`

It answered:

```
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142


npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
```

I didn't understand what should I do? Can anyone help me?

Comment: The dependencies for the library you’ve installed are deprecated. This can mean any number of things in reality, but you may be interested in urging the maintainers of `firebase-tools` to upgrade their dependencies if possible.

Answer (score 3):

to solve this problem I tried

```
npm update -g firebase-tools
```

But it doesn't work because the library is not supported anymore. Furthermore, firebase tools are obligatory for the `firebase login:ci` command  [to generate an authentication token for use in non-interactive environments.](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools) . But you know it was meaningless without firebase tools.

```
curl -sL firebase.tools | bash
```

This command line helps you to download and install CLI without any dependencies. It worked.

As a next step I typed:

```
firebase login:ci
```

But there was a mistake *again* :

```
Error: Cannot run login:ci in non-interactive mode.
```

to activate it:

```
firebase login --interactive
```

All these command lines were tested and approved,  **IT WORKS**

Comment: I did `npm uninstall -g firebase-tools` and then `curl -sL firebase.tools | bash` and it fixed everything