# Firebase Functions: UUID version is different for firebase-tools

Tags: npm, google-cloud-functions, npm-install, uuid, npm-update

When I deploy functions to Cloud Functions I get this warning:

```
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.3: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated debug@4.1.1: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1. (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/797)
npm WARN deprecated debug@4.1.1: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1. (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/797)
npm WARN deprecated debug@4.1.1: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1. (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/797)
npm WARN deprecated debug@4.1.1: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1. (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/797)
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated @manifoldco/swagger-to-ts@2.1.0: This package has changed to openapi-typescript
```

I have installed the latest version with `npm install uuid` and I still get the messages. When I looked deep in to `node_modules` folder, I saw that there are many `uuid` folders inside and their version is different. For example:

`../functions/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/istanbul-lib-processinfo/node_modules/uuid/package.json` is 3.4.0

`../functions/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/@types/uuid/package.json` is 8.3.1
`../ReactFirebase/functions/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/uuid/package.json` is 8.3.2
`../functions/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/request/node_modules/uuid/package.json` is 3.4.0

Apparentaly the older version is used here. How can I update them all to the same version?

Note: I have deleted the whole project and re-configured firebase from beginning and it is still the same.

Comment: Have you checked with this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72163587/npm-gives-depreciated-errors-when-trying-to-install-firebase-tools-for-flutter

Comment: @SandeepVokkareni There is actually no solution in that post. They simply ignore it. Everything works for me as well but the problem is deprecated version have security issues as written in the mesage.

Comment: Can you check with this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68471343/why-npm-install-g-firebase-tools-request-has-been-deprecated) @savante. There he has tried with this command "curl -sL firebase.tools | bash" which helps you to download and install CLI without any dependencies.

Comment: Thanks @SandeepVokkareni but it didn't work as well. It says: "Your machine already has firebase-tools@11.0.1 installed. Nothing to do." I checked and the version numbers above stayed the same.

Comment: Can you give a try with this [auto install script](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#mac-linux-auto-script) @savante